# Why is this classic ASP dropdown not selecting the correct values?

Tags: html, asp-classic

The first few dropdowns in the loop will work correctly (there are 3 test  records this is fetching from SQL). Why is this selecting the last value in the list for the 3rd value, and then continuing to select the last value for all empty clientnos() values?

```
<%For k = 0 to 4%>
<td colspan ="5"><select name = "clientnos(<%=k%>)" id="aliasInput" >
<option value=""></option>

<%
strSQL1 = "select cno, aliasname from Clients order by Aliasname asc"
Set rs1 = objConnection.Execute(strSQL1, ,adCmdText)
call ErrorHandler(err)
arr1 = rs1.GetRows()

for i = 0 to UBound(arr1,2)

    cno = trim(arr1(0,i))
    aliasname = trim(arr1(1,i))

%>

<%if cno <> clientnos(k) Then%><option value = "<%=cno%>"><%=aliasname%></option><%end if%>
<%if cno = clientnos(k) Then%><option value = "<%=cno%>" selected><%=aliasname%></option><%end if%>
<%
next

%>
</select></td>
<%next%>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the incorrect selection by initially defaulting to a blank selection and found that the initial value of the dropdown was causing the issue with the last record being incorrect on the dropdown. Here is the corrected code.

```
<td colspan ="5"><select name = "selectedclientnos(k)" id="aliasInput" >
<option value="" selected></option>
<%
strSQL1 = "select cno, aliasname from Clients order by Aliasname asc"
Set rs1 = objConnection.Execute(strSQL1, ,adCmdText)
call ErrorHandler(err)
arr1 = rs1.GetRows()

for i = 0 to UBound(arr1,2)

    cno = trim(arr1(0,i))
    aliasname = trim(arr1(1,i))

%>

<%if cno <> clientnos(k) Then%><option value = "<%=cno%>"><%=aliasname%></option><%end if%>
<%if cno = clientnos(k) Then%><option value = "<%=cno%>" selected><%=aliasname%></option><%end if%>
<%
next

%>
```